# How to get the cpu utilization % of another ec2 instance using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I need to get the CPU utilization % of another ec2 instance running in another region using python (boto3). Then if the CPU utilization is below a certain % mark, I need to stop that instance. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

**Amazon CloudWatch** collects [Amazon EC2 metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html). Metrics are collected every 5 minutes at no charge, but **detailed monitoring** can collect it every minute (additional charges apply).

If you are willing to accept this delay, then your application can request the metrics from CloudWatch [`get-metric-statistics`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_statistics), then make a [`stop-instances`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.stop_instances) call to EC2 to stop the instance.

Alternatively, you could use [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/), which will automatically start and stop instance based upon the metrics you define. No coding required.